# Errors when passing array or parameters to hstore scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope, hstore

I'm trying to create a scope on an hstore column in my Rails app.  Product is a model and features is an attribute of type hstore (using Postgresql 9.2). My class with scope is defined below:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :with_features, lambda {|features| where("foo_id in (?)", features)
```

The above scope only works if you pass single values in as features.  Arrays throw errors.  This is illustrated below:

```
Product.with_features('api')
  => [#<Product id: 1, name: "Sample">] 
     # so great success

# now with an array
Product.with_features(['api','mobile'])
  => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record 
    # so no good, this query will work as usual if features isn't of type hstore
```

In Rails 3.2, it seems support for postgres hstore type is limited when arrays are involved (I'm using https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore).  I've been trying some solutions with a each loop to append AND queries together, not much luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution I came up with that works well:

```
scope :with_features, lambda { |features| 

  #store the composed scope in local variable to build on
  composed_scope = self.scoped

  # if array, then loop through each
  if features.instance_of?(Array)
    features.each do |feature|
      composed_scope = composed_scope.where("features ? :key", :key => feature)
    end

  # otherwise, it's a single string parameter, parse as normal
  else
    composed_scope = composed_scope.where("features ? :key", :key => features)
  end

  # return the newly built composed scope
  composed_scope
}
```

Now both example queries above return expected results.